# JMeter Non HTTP response code: java.net.UnknownHostException when running on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, jmeter, load-testing, azure-virtual-machine, azure-aks

I am running my JMeter on Azure Kubernetes for load testing. JMeter uses HTTP sampler to call Azure function( HTTP endpoint) to generate load.
I am getting error message **Response code:Non HTTP response code: java.net.UnknownHostException Response message:Non HTTP response message: abcd.azurewebsites.net.** on kubernetes.

I ran my JMeter test in Azure virtual machine and I am not getting any issue.
I am using same test plan (jmx file) for both Kuberenetes and virtual machine and same Azure function is used in both cases.

Please let me know why getting error **Response code:Non HTTP response code: java.net.UnknownHostException Response message:Non HTTP response message: abcd.azurewebsites.net** when running on Kubernetes.

I am using following configurations

1. JMeter - 5.2.1
2. Kubernetes - 1.19.9
3. Jmx file has 150 threads

Regards,
Amit Agrawal

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that this is a JMeter problem, most probably your pod doesn't have the Internet access for some reason, you might want to get familiarized with the following materials:

- [Check required ports](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/#check-required-ports)
- [Debugging DNS Resolution](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/)

However if JMeter is the only piece of software having this problem you might want to [increase JMeter's logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) for HTTP protocol by adding the next lines to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />
<Logger name="org.apache.http.wire" level="error" />
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http" level="debug" />
```

One of the possible reasons is that locally you [configured JMeter to use your corporate proxy for accessing the Internet](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) and by accident forgot to remove this settings for your k8s deployment

Comment: We are not using any proxy while running on virtual machine.